# Cannot list step function tags from lambda

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-step-functions

I have wasted hours trying to find out why `stepfunctions.listTagsForResource(...)` is not defined when calling it from the AWS Lambda integrated editors like this:

```
const { tags } = await stepfunctions.listTagsForResource({
  resourceArn: process.env.STATE_MACHINE_ARN
}).promise()
```

`lambda.listTags(...)`, however, seems to be available. I feel really stupid asking a question that (seemingly) simple:

How do I access AWS Step Functions resource tags using the AWS SDK? The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/StepFunctions.html#listTagsForResource-property) certainly didn't help.

EDIT: It's worth noting that all the other `list` functions work as expected, `listTagsForResource` is the only one that is not defined.

Comment: Did you call this first ? :> const stepfunctions = new AWS.StepFunctions();

Comment: Yes, as I said all other methods work so the construction of the stepfunctions object works as expected i suppose!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short Answer:

The version of `aws-sdk` available for use in the inline AWS Lambda editor is commonly antiquated; the current version there does not define the `listTagsForResource` function.

#### Long Answer:

Right now, running the following in the inline editor shows the `aws-sdk` version is `2.290.0`:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk")
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    console.log(AWS.VERSION)
}
```

The latest version at this time (as in your docs link) is `2.409.0`, which does, indeed, define the `listTagsForResource` function. You can confirm this in the [v2.409.0 source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/v2.409.0/apis/states-2016-11-23.normal.json#L319).

`listTagsForResource` was not, unfortunately, available in [v2.290.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/v2.290.0/apis/states-2016-11-23.normal.json), so you won't be able to call it in the Lambda inline editor. (It appears that function was added in [this commit](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/commit/8db24fbf7abcd61b12feab0bf8374477bd126d77#diff-86c5fb219e4b5c5cc8de675d58dc1078R763) for [v2.382.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/v2.382.0/apis/states-2016-11-23.normal.json#L313).)

It's still possible to use this function in Lambda, just not through the snazzy inline editor--you would have to [build a package](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html) of your Node app and deploy it to Lambda as a Zip file.

So, your question isn't stupid at all; you've encountered a frustrating problem that all too often bites people wanting to try out something quickly in the inline editor.